# Jackson Polymorphism

Tags: oop, jackson

I have a class Animal and subclass Cat and Dog that extends Animal.
I have a class called Zoo having a variable as List;

i.e.

```
Class Animal {
  String name;
```

}

```
 Class Cat Extends Animal {
 String color;
}

Class Zoo {
  List<Animal> animalsInZoo;
  public void printAnimalClass()
  { 
    for(Animal a :animalsInZoo)
   {
    System.out.println(a.getClass.getName());
   } 
  }
 }
```

The object of zoo will have animals that can be objects of Animal or subclass of Animal
Following is sample JSON representation of Object of Zoo class.

```
 { "animalsInZoo" : 
   [
     {"name":"A"},
     {"name": "B","color":"white"}
   ]
  }
```

I have to convert this into java object in such a way that first animal in list get converted into Object of class Animal and second gets converted into object of Class Cat

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the conversion yourself, supposing you have another animal with same property:

```
Class Horse Extends Animal {
    String color;
}
```

jackson doesn't know convert {"name": "B","color":"white"} into Cat or Horse.

you may add a property to mark which animal you need to convert to.